# Anyone know how to initial a json import for jQuery.sheet?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jQuery.sheet extension found at: http://www.visop-dev.com/jquerysheet.html

Anyone have any experience with this plug in?  Im trying to import a json file on page load.  Following the demo I formatted my json output, but how do I load the output?  I have my load function to:

```
$('#sheet').sheet({
  buildSheet: jQuery.sheet.makeTable.json()
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help / pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
$.sheet.instance[0].makeTable.json()
```